# Observable Collection is not updating the datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, observablecollection

I am using a  `Dim All_PriceLists As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of BSPLib.PriceLists.PriceListPrime)` where `PriceListPrime` implements Inotify for all properties in it.

I bound the `All_PriceList` to a datagrid as `DataGrid1.ItemsSource = All_PriceLists` but when I do `All_PriceLists=Getall()` where Getall reads and gets the data from the DB, the datagrid is not updating.

It updates only when I hack it this way:

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Nothing
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = All_PriceLists
```

Could you please tell me where I have gone wrong or what I should implement.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several solutions to your problem

- Update the ItemsSource directly (instead of replacing the local member variable)

  ```
  DataGrid1.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection(Of PriceListPrime)(GetAll())
  ```
- Update the ObservableCollection (as mentioned in another answer)

  ```
  All_PriceList.Clear(); 
  For Each item in Getall() 
      All_PriceList.Add(item) 
  Next
  ```
- Set your DataContext to a view model and bind to a property of the view model

  ```
  Dim vm as new MyViewModel()
  DataContext = vm
  vm.Items = new ObservableCollection(Of PriceListPrime)(GetAll())
  ```

  The view model will implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raised the PropertyChanged event when the `Items` property is changed.  In the Xaml your DataGrid's `ItemsSource` will bind to the `Items` property.

Comment: If I use the MyViewModel completely instead of All_PriceLists could the binding work, also does this allow me to use querying with out using ctype because for previous oneis with (of T) type.  Would it? And could you please point me to a source that could provide more info on it.

Comment: Which bit do you need more info on?  I'm guessing it's MVVM and the use of the DataContext.  Search on SO, there will be plenty of resources.

Comment: Thats what a MVVM is for.  Thank you, I will try to spend more time on it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not updating the collection, you are replacing it, which is different.
The datagrid remains bound to the old list and the updated data is stored in a new unbound collection. So, you are not hacking a solution, your are binding the datagrid to the new collection, which is correct.

If you want a more automatic solution, you should bind your datagrid to a dataset/datatable, which is totally different code.

Comment: How can counter that situation, is there some property or method for the ObservableCollection?

Comment: You can do what is suggested by 'invisible' but your current solution is simpler and faster.

Answer (score 2):

You should update ObservableCollection instead of creating new one if you want the app to react on your changes.

So, clear `All_PriceList` collection and add new items into it. Example:

```
All_PriceList.Clear();
For Each item in Getall()
  All_PriceList.Add(item)
Next
```

ObservableCollection doesn't support AddRange, so you have to add items one by one or implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` in your own collection.